# TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tpe' in googlesearch

Tags: python, google-search

I am running fallowing code on google colab, which working perfectly.

```
from googlesearch import search
query_list = ["Grillen", 'Bratwurst', 'Holzkohle', 'Gasgrill', 'Barbecue']
for j in query_list:
    for i in search(j,  tld='com', lang='en', num=1, start=0, stop=1, pause=2.0,tpe="nws",):
        print (i)
```

However, if I run the same code in a python  virtual environment, I go the error:
 `TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tpe'`
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I replicate your situation on my system and it works. You try this piece of code it works perfectly.

```
pip install google
pip install beautifulsoup4

query_list = ["Grillen", 'Bratwurst', 'Holzkohle', 'Gasgrill', 'Barbecue']
for j in query_list:
    for i in search(j,  tld='com', lang='en', num=1, start=0, stop=1,pause=2.0,tpe="nws",):
        print (i)
```